# Replace field with MongoDB aggregate. Why $set, $addFields and $project, doesn't always replace the field?

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Passing an object to an existing field in `$set` or `$addFields` *merges* objects rather than replaces them, e.g.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/aXe-rExjCXr

```js
// Collection
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "options": {
      "size": "Large",
      "color": "Red"
    }
  }
]
```

```js
// Aggregate
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      options: {
        size: "Small"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

```js
// Expect
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "options": {
      "size": "Small"
    }
  }
]
```

```js
// Actual
[
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "options": {
      "size": "Small",
      "color": "Red" // <-- Not expected?
    }
  }
]
```

(It get's even weirder with arrays)

Is it possible to have it behave like non-object values and simply replace the field?

For context, I want to use this in an [aggregate update pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: The MongoDB docs don't explicitly explain the behaviour of passing an object like this -- however I've found that wrapping all values with `$literal` (e.g. { $set: { options: { $literal: { size: "Small" } } } } seems to work, but again, it's not explicitly documented so I'm not confident there'll be any gotchas?

Comment: I guess when considering how `$project` works with dot notation vs nested fields the behaviour of `$set` / `$addFields` becomes a bit more understandable https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#embedded-document-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, and as far as i know there is not plan to change, as far as i remembered there was a jira with this, but they closed it, meaning that it will not change i think.

`$set/$addFields` replace always except

- array field and i add document => array with all members that document
- document field and i add document => merge documents **(this is your case here)**

`$project` replace always except

- array field and i add document => array with all members that document

Solutions

- You can override this "weird" behaviour especially in case of
  arrays, by `$unset` the old field first for example, and then `$set`
- Based on the jira in the comment bellow, we can also use `$literal` to avoid this, but when we use `$literal` we have to be sure that we dont use expressions because they will not be evaluated.
  (expressions like path references, variables, operators etc)

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems reasonable to to unset all keys in a stage before the $set like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/m9lAjPg9qUF

Do you know if wrapping each field in `$literal` would also be a viable solution https://mongoplayground.net/p/uEvRuoUL1Ka

Comment: This might be the jira ticket you were referring to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53284 which does suggest `$literal` could also solve the issue.

Comment: i didn't remembered the `$literal` seems to work ok also, but if literal not expression will be evaluated(no reference field,variables etc). I think it was this jira. `$literal` seems fine, and if expressions i think `$unset` first.